# Laravel : Track number os continous sign in

Tags: php, laravel

Is there anyway to **store number of continues signin of a user** besides storing the number in database table.

Suppose a new user signup's and logins continuously 5 times then store the number of sign-ins for further use, Like the user will get a reward for that, Where i have a `reward` table and `reward_unlocked` table.

I haven't tried anything, Its kinda new thing.

I am using `laravel 5.2`

Comment: Please explain more in detail what you want to achieve and what you have already tried to achieve it.

Comment: @FrankProvost I have updated the question

Comment: And for what reason do you not want to store it in a database table? It seems like this is the way you want to go. What I basically understand is that you want to create a gamifiaction system. You will need to track a lot if "events" like logins. Therefore you could create a "history" table which stores all relevant events (e.g. ID | USER_ID | EVENT_TYPE ( e.g. login ) | DATE ) based on this table you can calculate your "reward"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved with `redis`.

Where i define the key with the user username and id increments with a simple if condition.

The id increments when the user logins and when a specific condition comes true a row adds to a table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store the login count number in a cookie with lifetime 5 years and for each login the user makes you use php function **file_put_contents('filename.txt', $your_data);** to write/rewrite the data in a text file.

But this has drawback , in case the cookies are deleted the count goes to 0.